# how to count a congestion in a node?

Tags: networking

Is there any idea,how it s possible to count congestions happened in a node as part of Network?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a network hardware guy, but I believe they may be able (on some devices) measure things like how full a buffer is (in bound or out bound), how many packets are in a queue waiting to be transmitted, or number of packet dropped because the buffer is full.  Switches/routers that have these features built in probably have other metrics like packet counts or even bandwidth usage that would give you a clear picture how traffic is flowing.

These features are usually on SOHO or larger devices.  However, I've seen some nice managed switches for about $300, so they aren't too expensive.

I'm sure someone with their CISCO certification could explain things better than I did.